# List of enums: I have 2 enums and I have to make a list/array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, enums, enum-map

pretty newbie question I think but I've spent over 6 hours doing this one way and another and I don't know whats the best way doing it, so I am asking for your help about how it is suppost to be done.

I have 2 enums, for example car and bike. I have to make `list` or `array` (I don't know which is better) that has 2 - 1 000 000 elements inside and when it's done I have to reorder the `list`/`array` (bikes at the beginning and cars in the end). There are only a bike and a car, but there can be hundreds or thoulsands or even more of them. I don't know if it's possible to make `EnumMap` about 2 enums.

`EnumMap` has key and value, so I gave key "car" and value "0", and key "bike" value "1", so it would be easier to reorder, but I found out I can't do this on `EnumMap`, because does't matter how much elements I add, there is always only 2, bike and car. Can't talk about hundreds there I assume.

The reason why I haven't focused on array, is in the beginning of code there is `enum garage {bike, car};`

This is homework yes, but I just hope to find out the method for doing it (spent hours just reading and trying different approaches), not that someone does it for me.

Comment: Use a List if you don't know how many elements you need. If you use an `ArrayList` it's ultimately backed by an array anyway.

Comment: I fear that you may be misunderstanding your assignment. My suggestion is that you post the actual assignment text here verbatim, so that we could make sure that you're interpretting things correctly, and if not, so that we could explain what you need to do. My guess is that you need to make a class that *contains* an enum field, and that you need to create a collection of objects of this class, but this is just a SWAG.

Comment: An EnumMap is probably not the way to go. Instead, consider using a [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) with [`Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: I post the correct then, but i wont let it be long im afraid, i just try to find out what i need to do :P

Comment: Okay there is said array, so I need to do that

Comment: OK, the thing about an enum is that there is only ever ONE sheep object, and only ONE goat object.  So your output will actually consist of a number of references to the sheep object, followed by a number of references to the goat object.  So can't you just count how many sheep references and how many goat references there are in the original array, then construct a new array with the right number of each in the right order?

Comment: And actually, I'd like to see the assignment text in the original language, because I don't know what "possibly fast" means.

Comment: I think I understand now and I understand what enum is now. There are ONE sheep object, but there can be like 1st, 2nd, 3rd.... 17th sheep, so, they are still sheeps but different ones. Same thing for goats right? And then I just have to make another array that takes sheep object and reorders the number of references.

Comment: This is original language. Its on estonian and on english, I can't translate it better than professor. The reorder should take less time than 25 milliseconds, otherwise we need to make new method, that is faster.

Comment: OK, I'll have a go at turning my solution into code.  I'm not sure whether it fits exactly what your professor requires.  But you can have a look and see how you feel about it.

Comment: It would be huge help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you split the logic into two methods, first `countGoats(Animal[])` -

```
private static int countGoats(Animal[] animals) {
    int count = 0;
    for (Animal a : animals) {
        if (Animal.goat == a) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Since every element up to the `goats` count should be a `goat` in the array (and every element after a `sheep`) we can then iterate the array with something like,

```
public static void reorder(Animal[] animals) {
    if (animals == null) {
        return;
    }
    int goats = countGoats(animals);
    for (int i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
        // if (i < goats) - it's a goat, otherwise it's a sheep.
        animals[i] = (i < goats) ? Animal.goat : Animal.sheep;
    }
}
```

This is an example of a [Counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) and has a run-time complexity of O(n). As the Wikipedia article notes,

> Because counting sort uses key values as indexes into an array, it is not a comparison sort, and the Ω(n log n) lower bound for comparison sorting does not apply to it.

Comment: Focused in this approach more and it did the trick. Big thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, based on what I understand. You are required to have a `List` of `Animals`, and implement a method `public static void reorder(ArrayList<Animal> animals)` to reorder this List.

This is what I've come up:

```
public class EnumHw {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<Animal>();

        animalList.add(Animal.GOAT);
        animalList.add(Animal.SHEEP);
        animalList.add(Animal.GOAT);
        animalList.add(Animal.SHEEP);

        EnumHw.reorder(animalList);

        for (Animal animal : animalList) {
            System.out.println(animal);
        }
    }

    public static void reorder(ArrayList<Animal> animals) {        
        Collections.sort(animals);        
    }
}

enum Animal {
    //Order you enum in the way you want them to come first in the List
    GOAT,
    SHEEP;    
}
```

Hope it'll help you (and you are allowed to use the `Collections` API. :)

Comment: You don't need to add an `order` field, because enums are already comparable by themselves, and they compare in their *natural* order (the order in which the constants are defined): `public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>> implements Comparable<E>, Serializable` <-- see the `Comparable<E>` part.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, sorry, my mistake. Already fixed it. Thank you. I was just thinking maybe he'll declare his enum constants in an unordered way. In his given example he has this `enum Animal {sheep, goat};`

Comment: @J.Lucky I understand this totally now but unfortunatly I need to work on it a bit more :P Thanks for explaining your method.

Comment: @J.Lucky It was helpful, but I can't do this with your method. I posted new post below about how it has to be (atleast I think so).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void reorder(Animal[] animals) {
    int sheepCount = 0; 
    int goatCount = 0;
    for (Animal oneAnimal : animals) {
        if (oneAnimal == Animal.sheep) {
            sheepCount++;
        } else {
            goatCount++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sheepCount; i++) {
        animals[i] = Animal.sheep;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < goatCount; i++) {
        animals[i + sheepCount] = Animal.goat;
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, this `for (Animal oneAnimal : animals)...` made so much sense right now.